# Javascript - Canvas drawImage transform cube

Tags: javascript, canvas, transform, drawimage

I have a script which creates a 3D cube thanks to a canvas WebGL. I would like to add an image on one of the face of the cube. However, I have some difficulties to find the way to correctly handle the transform of the image in order to have the image on the cube face.

Here the script which loops through each face of the cube in order to generate the lines:

```
canvas.ctx.beginPath();
canvas.ctx.moveTo( this.p0.X, this.p0.Y );
canvas.ctx.lineTo( this.p1.X, this.p1.Y );
canvas.ctx.lineTo( this.p2.X, this.p2.Y );
canvas.ctx.lineTo( this.p3.X, this.p3.Y );
canvas.ctx.closePath();
```

I don't know how to calculate the transform from my points... in order to add an image transformed regarding the cube:

```
canvas.ctx.save();
canvas.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
canvas.ctx.fillStyle = "black"
canvas.ctx.fillText('text',this.p0.X + ((this.p1.X - this.p0.X)/2), this.p0.Y + ((this.p1.Y - this.p0.Y)/2));
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
canvas.ctx.drawImage(img, this.p0.X, this.p0.Y, fl, fl);
canvas.ctx.transform(a, b, c, d, e, f);
canvas.ctx.restore();
```

It's more a mathematical issue I guess.

Comment: Are you even using 'WebGL'? To me it seems you're using '2d' context. I don't see any 'WebGL' canvas methods.

Comment: I use some WebGL lighting for the cube. The image is drawn in 2d context and I just need to transform it.

Comment: if you already have a webgl context for *lighting*, why don't you simply use webgl to draw the cube and apply this image as a texture on it? This is a job for webgl, even if you could maybe try to hack something with 2d ctx. Also, you're not waiting for your img has loaded before trying to draw it + you are setting the context's transform after your drawings have been done...